# Prestashop Web Service API keeps asking for authentication

Tags: php, api, authentication, get, prestashop

I am having this problem I enabled the webservice from prestashop and I can access it if I write the URL directly passing the parameter from post method 
http://underwearstudio.mx/pruebas/api?&ws_key="mykey".

But If I try to access without passing the ws_key as parameter it keeps asking me to authenticate.

From what I read when authentication is prompted you need to use the API key as username and leave the blank password, but it just keeps prompting the authentication.

What can I do?

I was trying to follow this tutorial.(http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+2+-+Discovery+-+Testing+access+to+the+web+service+with+the+browser)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 18):

For googlers such as myself:

Since version, 1.6.1.1, one need to add this code [`?&ws_key=YourSecretKey`] at the end of the url and access the webservice with this method, as the passing as username (stated in the docs) does not work

```
 http://[YourPrestaShopUrl]/api?&ws_key=YourSecretKey

 eg: http://192.168.1.148/api/products?limit=5&ws_key=EUQ1J6NT1KVJ1S9SYGRCLGQE8IJU66DA
```

to accomplish this using [the webservice library](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib) , you may add this line :

```
$url .= '&ws_key=' . $this->key;
```

at line 156 (in current version), which is in the

```
 protected function executeRequest($url, $curl_params = array())
```

and right before the initializing the cURL :

```
$session = curl_init($url);
```

Comment: following the link of your request, someone has answered that the server should lack some configurations AND/OR a properly formed .htaccess file, do you know which are those confs or htaccess contents?

Comment: @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' perhaps what you are looking for is the second answer here, but I assure you my workaround works

Comment: As of PrestaShop version: 1.7.6.2 the solution provided by @MuhammadNaderi is still the easiest way of dealing with this issue. @MatteoBononi'peorthyr' one of the server configurations lacking suggested in the linked request is `basic auth mod`, I confirmed that it is not the case (at least not in my situation).

Answer (score 4):

Just create an .htaccess within webservice folder with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello I am also gone through same problem if You want to avoid that authentication of prestashop then you can add the consumer key for that prestashop store in api url such as follows

http://localhost:8080/prestashop/api/products/2/?ws_key=TCXXHYPCT8DHWW64QXU1KEQVF4PQ1SJ6

here while accessing products details you can add consume key to access the products details.
It can be also useful when if you are using prestashop web service apis in other platform.
Thanks

Comment: This exact hint has been given before. Anything new you want to contribute?

Answer (score 1):

From [their documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Webservice+one-page+documentation#Webserviceone-pagedocumentation-UsingHTTPrequests), it looks like you should be able to put your API key into the URL in place of where a username would go in a regular HTTP request, e.g:

```
http://[yourapikeyhere]@example.com/api/customers/
```

This quote from "Testing access to the web service with the browser":

> The shop should prompt you for a username and a password to enter. The ID is the authentication key and there is no password.

... seems to match up with what you said about the username vs password. It looks like these guys are using the API key as the username in a regular HTTP basic authentication sense with no password (otherwise would be `http://user:password@example.com`), which seems to match up with the RESTful URL example they provided above. If basic authentication via your browser isn't working, I'd suggest it's more likely either that your API key is wrong - keep in mind it's highly likely to be case sensitive.

Comment: I already did that and it keeps prompting for username and password, in fact it was the first thing I tried. Thank you

Comment: @JuanJaimeEduardoMontemayor did you solve this problem? I am having the same exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since prestashop 1.7.4, they are providing an alternate method.

ie; to access `http://yourstore.com/api/`

it will prompt for username/password.

Enter the key you generated as username and leave password field empty.

This will give you an output like

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <api shopName="Tureds">
    <products xlink:href="https://www.tureds.com/api/products" get="true" put="false" post="true" delete="false" head="false">
      <description xlink:href="https://www.tureds.com/api/products" get="true" put="false" post="true" delete="false" head="false"> The products</description>
      <schema xlink:href="https://www.tureds.com/api/products?schema=blank" type="blank"/>
      <schema xlink:href="https://www.tureds.com/api/products?schema=synopsis" type="synopsis"/>
    </products>
  </api>
</prestashop>
```

[image]

Remember

1. to enable webservice in the backend.
2. No need to regenerate .htaccess file. Regeneration of .htaccess file is for older versions of
   prestashop.