# I can't add an image Web Service Prestashop

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop-1.6

When I try to add an image to a product I don't get any errors, but the image doesn't get added.

This is my code:

```
 function addImage($idProduct)
        {

            $key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
            $url = "http://192.168.1.81/api/images/products/".$idProduct;
            $image_path = 'image2.jpg';

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => '@'.$image_path.';type=image/jpg'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);

            echo '<h2>Image Added</h2>'; 

        }
```

I also made a change on PSWebServiceLibrary.php, because Prestashop Web Service API keeps asking for authentication. This is the link where I got the code [Prestashop Web Service API keeps asking for authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749812/prestashop-web-service-api-keeps-asking-for-authentication) .

This is the code I added:

```
     $url .= '&ws_key=' . $this->key;
```

The problem is that the code to add an image was working before I made that change on PSWebServiceLibrary.php, and I don't know how to solve it.
I am using prestashop 1.6.1.5

Any help will be appreciated.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

I think it's only a missing of "?" in your url.

If I follow your $url logic the result will be for product of ID 1234567 by example :
http://192.168.1.81/api/images/products/1234567&ws_key=ZOEJFD3429JD209AZJX0DJF20

So your server waits this url to hanlde ws_key as GET parameter :
http://192.168.1.81/api/images/products/1234567?ws_key=ZOEJFD3429JD209AZJX0DJF20

You need to add this "?" at the end of you URL like this :

```
$url = "http://192.168.1.81/api/images/products/".$idProduct."?";
```

Best Regards,

TGA

Comment: i was looking for solution last 2 days and its works like charm !! Thanks , +1 From my side

Answer (score 2):

For me works like this:

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => curl_file_create($image_path)));

Comment: Thank you so much!